# Convert stored procedure to Linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting runtime errors when I try and convert this stored procedure to a Linq statement about missing `}`.I am not sure if I am doing the CASE statement  correct in linq. Is there a better way to do this?

SQL

```
SELECT TOP 1
    C.CustomerId,
    Institution = (SELECT TOP 1 
                       CASE Name 
                          WHEN 'In1' THEN 'Institution 1' 
                          ELSE Name 
                       END 
                   FROM [Group] G 
                   JOIN CustomerXrefs X ON X.GroupId = G.GroupId AND G.GroupTypeId = 308 
                   WHERE X.CustomerId = C.CustomerId),
    G.GroupId   
FROM    
    Customer C
JOIN 
    CustomerXrefs X ON C.CustomerId = X.CustomerId
JOIN 
    [Group] G ON X.GroupId = G.GroupId
WHERE
    C.Email = @Email
    AND G.GroupTypeId = 308
ORDER BY 
    G.GroupId
```

Linq

```
var query1 = 
    (from c in db.Customers
     join cx in db.CustomerXrefs on c.CustomerId equals cx.CustomerId
     join g in db.Groups on cx.GroupId equals g.GroupId
     select new Customer
     {
        CustomerId = c.CustomerId,
        Institution = (from ig in db.Groups
                       join icx in db.CustomerXrefs 
                       on ig.GroupId equals icx.GroupId && ig.GroupTypeId == 308
                       where icx.CustomerId == c.CustomerId
                       select new Institution
                       {
                           Name = ig.Name == "In1 " ? "Institution 1" :
                                  ig.Name == "In2" ? "Institution 2" :
                                  ig.Name
                       }).FirstOrDefault();
     }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You need to move the `&& ig.GroupTypeId == 308` into the `where`, or you need to change the join condition to `on new { ig.GroupId, ig.GroupTypeId} equals new { micgx.GroupId, GroupTypeId = 308}` as you cannot tack on extra stuff to the join condition like that.

Comment: Also it looks like it should be `icx.GroupId` and not `micgx.GroupId`

Comment: Thanks is the  new Institution correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got rid of all errors by simulating with classes

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataBase db = new DataBase();

            var query1 = (from c in db.Customers
                          join cx in db.CustomerXrefs on c.CustomerId equals cx.CustomerId
                          join g in db.Groups on cx.GroupId equals g.GroupId
                          select new Customer
                          {
                              CustomerId = c.CustomerId,
                              Institution = (from ig in db.Groups
                                             join icx in db.CustomerXrefs on ig.GroupId equals icx.GroupId
                                             where icx.CustomerId == c.CustomerId && ig.GroupTypeId == 308
                                             select new Institution()
                                             {
                                                 Name = ig.Name == "In1 " ? "Institution 1" :
                                                        ig.Name == "In2" ? "Institution 2" :
                                                        ig.Name
                                             }
                                             ).FirstOrDefault()
                          });
 

        }
 
    }
    public class DataBase
    {
        public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public List<CustomerXrefs> CustomerXrefs { get; set; }
        public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    }
    public class Customer
    {
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Institution Institution { get; set; }
    }
    public class CustomerXrefs
    {
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string GroupId { get; set; }
    }
    public class Group
    {
        public string GroupId { get; set; }
        public int GroupTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Institution
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```